# Wpf datagridview wrap cell content

Tags: c#, wpf

Friends
 I'm new using wpf datagridview view. I filled the grid using oledataadapter and datatable.
My problem is cell content. I want wrap text in grid cell
How can I do that?
Please give me full instruction, if you have used xaml style because I tried some style and it didn't work.

Comment: Please show your xaml, code

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting the style for DatagridTextColumn as shown below,

```
<DataGrid.Columns>               
    <DataGridTextColumn>
         <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
             <Style>                            
                 <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />             
             </Style>
         </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

It should work.

Comment: Mahadev Bk should i put this code in xaml insdie datagrid view control thank you

Comment: mahadev bk please note i'm using datatable to fill datagrid should this code work

Comment: This would work, if you are binding each column separately to respective  Property and bind DataContext.  If you want to use DataTable to bind dgView.DataSource.                                                                                        Try setting the property dgView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;